# Change width of ellipse when zooming

Tags: d3.js, zooming

I am trying to create a heatmap in D3js with a zoom and pan feature. So far, my pan function works as it should, but I have a minor problem with zoom feature.

The zoom feature should only scale (stretch/squeeze) in the direction of the x-axis, which it does at the moment. Right now, the initial view of the heatmap—when I load the script—shows me the entire dataset with squeezed dots, which is what I want. The problem is that the squeezed dots stay squeezed when I zoom in, which leads to a huge gaps between them. What I would like is to scale the `dotWidth` of the SVG ellipses (the dots) to avoid this. However, I am not sure how to implement it. Below is some code samples from my script.

To be more specific: If the initial height and width of the ellipse is 1 and 3, respectively, I would like the width to scale between 1 and 3, so it becomes a circle under max zoom.

**Create heatmap:**

```
var dotWidth = 1
var dotHeight = 3

// Heatmap ellipes
svg.selectAll("ellipse")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("ellipse")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(d.day) + paddingLeft; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d.hour); })
    .attr("rx", dotWidth)
    .attr("ry", dotHeight)
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
        return "rgba(100, 200, 200, " + colorScale(d.tOutC) + ")";
    });
```

**Create zoom:**

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 3])
    .x(xScale)
    .on("zoom", zoomHandler);

function zoomHandler() {
    var t = zoom.translate(),
        tx = t[0],
        ty = t[1];

    tx = Math.min(tx, 0); // tx < 0
    tx = Math.max(tx,  -1000); //
    zoom.translate([tx, ty]);

    svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    svg.selectAll("ellipse")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(d.day) + paddingLeft; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d.hour); });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you created new x and y positions for the ellipses but didn´t actually change their radius.  For a circle it works like that:

```
var scaleMultiplier = d3.event.scale;
```

circles
    .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return xAxisScale(d.cx); })
    .attr("cy", function(d, i) { return yAxisScale(d.cy); })
    .attr("r",  function(d, i) { return (d.radius * scaleMultiplier); });
}

Comment: Thanks @Karolinka, that help me out. I actually just need to add `.attr("rx", function(d) { return (dotWidth * d3.event.scale); })` to the zoomHandler function..